# Best way to render Twitter emojis from twitter in html?

Tags: php, regex, json, twitter, unicode

So I have the json object from a query of the twitter api.  In it's raw form, the text is like this:

`"check out this emoji \ud83d\udc98"`

I've spent a lot of time reading about unicode and it's formats, and I've managed a library that has the json unicode as the keys like this:

```
$emoji_dictionary = array(
  '\ud83d\udd39'=> array(
    'emoji-id'=> 'e-B76', 
    'codepoint'=> 'U+1F539', 
    'name'=> 'SMALL BLUE DIAMOND', 
    'twitter-id'=> '1f539'
  ), 
  '\ud83d\ude3f'=> array(
    'emoji-id'=> 'e-34D', 
    'codepoint'=> 'U+1F63F', 
    'name'=> 'CRYING CAT FACE', 
    'twitter-id'=> '1f63f'
  ), 

  ...
);
```

So now I've been trying like hell to evaluate the json unicode that I got from twitter as a string, which I can then throw in to this function:

```
function get_src($str) {
    echo 'regex found:' . $str . '<br />';
    return '<img class="twitter-emoji" src="https://abs.twimg.com/emoji/v1/72x72/' . $emoji_dictionary[$str]['twitter-id'] . '.png"/>';
  }
```

Which returns an image from twitter of that emoji, but I can't seem to `preg_replace` the json data properly in PHP.  I get this error sometimes:

```
preg_replace(): Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u
```

My preg_replace is like this (note that this does not work):

```
  $text = strval(json_encode($twitter_datum->text));
  $pattern = "/\\\\u([a-f0-9]{4})/e";
  $text = preg_replace($pattern, "get_src($1)", $text;
```

This pattern grabs 'd83d' and 'dc98' separately.

Is what I'm trying to do impossible?  I just want to get `1f498` (from the dictionary) from `"check out this emoji!! \ud83d\udc98"`

Answer (score 3):

To anyone trying to do something like this, here's what I've learned:

String operations on something `json_encodeed` is a bad idea.  I was doing this because I couldn't see the unicode expression but little boxes instead & thus and didn't know how to evaluate them.

[Emoji for PHP](http://code.iamcal.com/php/emoji/) is a GREAT resource for this sort of thing.   It can swap out any unicode emoji occurrence with `<span class="xxx'></span>`, where the `xxx` maps to a sprite of that emoji.  It does something similar to what I was trying to do, but for two main differences:

- The code's regex is on the json_decoded entity
- Rather than replacing it with an `<img>` with an src going to twitter, this goes to `<span>` with reference to a local png

My code now looks like this, and it is working fine.  The only issue is if/when new emojis are added, they will not be recognized by this script.   Maybe at that point emojis will be a little more universal, w/ full browser support, etc.  Here's what I have:
$json

```
function twitter_chron() {
  $json = get_tweets(50);
  $twitter_data = json_decode($json); 
  include(ABSPATH . 'wp-content/themes/custom/emoji/emoji.php');

    foreach($twitter_data as $twitter_datum) {
        $id = $twitter_datum->id;
        if (property_exists($twitter_datum, 'retweeted_status')) {
          $text = 'RT: ' . $twitter_datum->retweeted_status->text;
        } else {
          $text = $twitter_datum->text;
        }
        $text = emoji_unified_to_html($text);
        $text = iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//IGNORE", $text);
        insert_tweet($id, $text, $date);
    } 
}
```

The `emoji_unified_to_html($text)` is from the `emoji.php`.  I have additional functions that I run against the tweet body for links, hashtags & mentions but I figure it's not relevant to this particular issue of emojis.

Hope this helps someone.